# Turning a covariance sum into an integral

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, covariance, auto-correlation

I am reading Lorenzo's Bergomi's book *Stochastic Volatility Modeling*, and I have come to this passage.[image]

I just would like to understand the derivation between the first and the second equality. I guess I just have to "correctly" re-express the integral and then use Fubini's theorem so as to obtain an integral with just a $dt$/$du$/whatever term that turns into the $T - \tau$ term, but I can't figure how to do the right change of variables as $t - u$ is a function of $t$ **and** $u$. Any idea over there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the function $f$ only depends on $|t-u|$, meaning it is actually symmetric: $f(x)=f(-x)$. Doing the change of variable $\tau:=t-u$:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^Tdu\int_0^Tf(t-u)dt
&=\int_0^Tdu\int_{-u}^{T-u}f(\tau)d\tau
\\
&=\int_0^Tdu\left(\int_0^{T-u}f(\tau)d\tau+\int_0^uf(\tau)d\tau\right)
\\
&=\int_0^T{du \left(\int_0^T{f(\tau) \textbf{1}_{\tau \leq T - u} d\tau}
+ \int_0^T{f(\tau) \textbf{1}_{\tau \leq u}d\tau}\right)}
\\
&=\int_0^T{f(\tau)d\tau \left(\int_0^T{ \textbf{1}_{u \leq T - \tau} du}
+ \int_0^T{\textbf{1}_{u \geq \tau}du}\right)}
\\
&=\int_0^Tf(\tau)d\tau\left(\int_0^{T-\tau}du+\int_\tau^Tdu\right)
\\
&=2\int_0^T(T-\tau)f(\tau)d\tau
\end{align}$$
For the second equality, note that $0\leq u\leq T$ hence $-u\leq0$ and $0\leq T-u$.

Comment: @siou0107 the indicators are a nice touch, thanks, even clearer now.